# While Indexing (ElasticClient.IndexMany()) throws StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, indexing, nest

I used to get my documents from Database like that:

```
private List<Student> GetStudents()
        {
                using (Context context = new Context(connectionString))
                {
                    return context.Students
                        .ToList<Student>(); 
                }
        }
```

And then I indexed some documents with IndexMany() and everything was good.

But when I Include "User": to my Documents like that:

```
private List<Student> GetStudents()
        {
                using (Context context = new Context(connectionString))
                {
                    return context.Students
                        .Include(s => s.User)
                        .ToList<Student>(); 
                }
        }
```

Program works until "client.IndexMany(students,studentsIndexName);" and than throws
"StackOverFlowException" in unknown Module

```
public int InitializeStudents()
        {
            string studentsIndexName = "students";
            client.Indices.Create(GetStudentMap(studentsIndexName));
            List<Student> students = GetStudents();

            client.IndexMany(students,studentsIndexName);

            return students.Count;
        }
```

I have about 1000 documents in collection and
at first a tryed to index only part of them (5) but i had the same problem
Then I thought that problem appears beсause index upadates too often so i disabled upadating while indexing,
but it also didn't help

```
public int InitializeStudents()
    

        {
                string studentsIndexName = "students";
                client.Indices.Create(GetStudentMap(studentsIndexName).Settings(s => s
                .RefreshInterval(-1)
                ));
                List<Student> students = GetStudents();
    
                client.IndexMany(students.Take<Student>(5),studentsIndexName);
    
                client.Indices.UpdateSettings(studentsIndexName, s => s.IndexSettings(o => o.RefreshInterval(1)));
                return students.Count;
            }
    
    
    private static CreateIndexDescriptor GetStudentMap(string indexName)
            {
                CreateIndexDescriptor map = new CreateIndexDescriptor(indexName);
                map.Mappings(M => M
                    .Map<Student>(m => m
                        .Properties(prop => prop
                            .Text(s => s
                                .Name(n => n.FullName)
                            )
                            
                            .Object<User>(o => o
                                .Name(s => s.User)
                                
    
                             )
                            .Number(s => s
                               .Name(n => n.Id)
                               .Type(NumberType.Integer)
                            )
                        )
                     )
                  )
               ;
                return map;
    
            }
```

I use Elasticsearch.Net 7.10 and EntityFramework 5.0.
So can you give some ideas what is wrong or what should I try, please?

Comment: Most likely your user has a reference to student which has a reference to user and so on... StackOverfkowException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, it sounds like there may be a circular reference in the `Student` and `User` types. The JSON serializer used by the NEST 7.x does not handle circular references, which would lead to a stack overflow.

I would strongly recommend defining simple POCOs for the documents that will be indexed into Elasticsearch, and mapping the domain types to these.

If you *really* want to index the types you have, then you may be able to use the [`JsonNetSerializer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer) to do so, [which can be configured to handle circular references](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#ReferenceLoopHandling).

Comment: Thank you very much, I used JsonNetSerializer as you advised, and now it works.